# Reading from multiple BlockingQueues within a single thread

Tags: java, select, blockingqueue

I have three Java's `LinkedBlockingQueue` instances and I'd like to read from them (`take` operation) only using one thread. The naive approach is to have one thread per queue.

Is there anything like the UNIX `select` system call for blocking queues in Java?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want a mutual exclusion for the three queues, that is one thread can read from one of the three queues at a time?

Answer (score 2):

Well, those BlockingQueues were really meant to be serviced by their own Threads.

Something I'd consider trying is to set up a 4th queue for much smaller items, say `Boolean`s, and have the `offer()` calls on each of the 3 other queues accompany their insertion by inserting a Boolean into that 4th queue. Your thread can then go to sleep on the 4th queue, and when it wakes up it can `peek()` in the other 3 to find out where to get the goods.

Highly inelegant solution, I think, and I suspect there are possible race conditions where you won't be cleanly woken up some times. But it should basically work.

Comment: the 4th queue can be queue of queues. when adding an element into the *ith* queue, add the *ith* queue to the 4th queue. the thread blocked on 4th queue take() will get the *ith* queue which *may* contain a new element.

Comment: That's a fiendishly clever idea! +1.